# Restrict user from selecting the same choice in 3 drop-down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 selects which I would like to restrict the user from selecting the same option. Should the user select the first option i.e 'Select' then the other drop downs should show all the values.The restriction works but when I select the first option i.e select,it does not populate the rest of the selects with all the values

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/lM7yB3gLhMCWyI5z

```
<select id="sel1" class='agency'>
      <option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="EIS">EIS</option>
      <option value="Exp">Exp</option>
      <option value="TUL">TUL</option>
  </select>
   <select id="sel2" class='agency'>
      <option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="EIS">EIS</option>
      <option value="Exp">Exp</option>
      <option value="TUL">TUL</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sel3" class='agency'>
      <option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="EIS">EIS</option>
      <option value="Exp">Exp</option>
      <option value="TUL">TUL</option>
  </select>


$(function () {


        var elements = [];
        $('.agency').each(function (i, obj) {
            elements.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });

        var arr = ['EIS', 'EXP', 'TUL'];
        $('.agency').change(function () {

            debugger;
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var selected = $("#" + id + "  option:selected").text();;
            var filteredElements = $(elements).filter(function (idx) {
                return elements[idx] !== id;
            });

            var y = $.grep(arr, function (value) {
                return value.trim() != selected.trim();
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < filteredElements.length; i++) {

                var $selectobject = $("#" + filteredElements[i]);
                var currentID = $selectobject.attr('id');

                var selctedText = $("#" + currentID + "  option:selected").text();;
                var currentArr=[];

                $("#" + currentID + "  option").each  ( function() {
                    currentArr.push ( $(this).text() );
                });
                $("#" + currentID).html('');
               $("#" + currentID).prepend('<option value=' + 0 + '>  Select </option>');
                $.each(y, function (index, value) {
                    $("#" + currentID).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + value + ' </option>');
                });

                $("#" + currentID).prepend("<option value='0' 'selected'></option>");

                var x = y.filter(function (elem) {
                    return elem.trim() !== selctedText.trim();
                });
                y = x;
                debugger;

            }
        });






    });
```

**I have edited the code to show what I have worked on**

Comment: (1) Paste that code here and format it.  (2) Please show us what you have tried and we can build upon that.

Comment: I posted the plunker link earlier but i have edited the code to show what i did